# Verilog code error for seven segment display

Tags: verilog

I have tried every single variant of this code for the seven segment display code and it always keeps saying error. I don't know why.

```
module sevensegment (input [3:0] bcd, output reg [6:0] seg);
always @ (*)
      case(bcd)
      0: seg = 7’b0111111; 
      1: seg = 7’b0000110;   
      2: seg = 7’b1011011;
      3: seg = 7’b1001111;
      4: seg = 7’b1100110;
      5: seg = 7’b1101101;
      6: seg = 7’b1111101;
      7: seg = 7’b0000111;
      8: seg = 7’b1111111;
      9: seg = 7’b1101111;
      default:  seg = 7’b0000000;
    endcase  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help others understand your problem quicker if you explained more than just "saying error". I assume you got a syntax error because you are using curly single quote ’  instead of a straight single quote `'`

Comment: It says unprintable character for every single case :0 , 1, 2 etc... In many tutorials it is accepted the curly single quote ’ as valid, and I think it is the only valid one.

Comment: You might have to re-enter the single quote and in your editor turn "smart-quotes" off.

Comment: Done it, still it keeps saying like 10 messages of error. Does this code work for you with that though?

Answer (score 1):

you probably use `utf-8` encoding in your editor. This might result in unprintable unicode chars. Switch to `ascii-8` if you can. Here is the fixed code which compiles:

```
module sevensegment (input [3:0] bcd, output reg [6:0] seg);
always @ (*)
      case(bcd)
      0: seg = 7'b0111111; 
      1: seg = 7'b0000110;   
      2: seg = 7'b1011011;
      3: seg = 7'b1001111;
      4: seg = 7'b1100110;
      5: seg = 7'b1101101;
      6: seg = 7'b1111101;
      7: seg = 7'b0000111;
      8: seg = 7'b1111111;
      9: seg = 7'b1101111;
      default:  seg = 7'b0000000;
    endcase  
endmodule
```